# finding values located in one column in a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, octave

I'm trying to find values in a multidimensional array which are only in one column.  I can find the correct values when searching the entire multidimensional array.  But if I try and limit the find in the multidimensional array to say just the second column the values are not the expected ones.

example of code and **correct** output:

```
A = [2 4 6; 8 10 12]
A(:,:,2) = [5 7 9; 11 13 15]
A(:,:,3) = [55 4 55; 167 167 154]

[row,col,page]=ind2sub(size(A), find(A(:,1,:)==4))

row =1,1
col =2,2
page =1,3
```

But If I try and limit the find to just the second column using these commands

```
[row,col,page]=ind2sub(size(A), find(A(:,2,:)==4)) 

row =1,1
col =1,3
page =1,1
```

I get values that are different from the expected ones.  **I'm trying to limit the multidimensional find to search all pages, all rows, and one specific column.**  The output should be the same as the first example. How can I fix this?

Comment: From what I have understood, you are looking to basically find the row and page numbers, when searching along a specific column. Thus, you can focus on finding just the row and page numbers. You can use this - `[row,~,page]=ind2sub([size(A,1) 1 size(A,3)],find(A(:,col_num,:)==4))`, where `col_num` would be the column number that you are searching along. The trick is to use `1` instead of `size(A,2)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `[m,n,o]=size(A)`, you are using `A(:,2,:)==4` which is a matrix n*1*o. `ind2sub` expects a n*m*o matrix. Typical approach is using a mask:

```
mask=false(size(A));
mask(:,2,:)=true;
[i,j,k]=ind2sub(size(A), find((A(:,:,:)==4)&mask))
```

The mask selects the entries you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24248693/2586922) works by defining a mask and then searching throughout the whole array with that mask applied. The following limits the search to the desired column, and thus may be faster for large arrays:

```
col = 2; %// desired column
[row, page] = ind2sub([size(A,1) size(A,3)], find(A(:,col,:)==4));
```

If you need `col` as a vector the same size as `row` and `page`, you can of course achieve it with `col = repmat(col,size(row))`.